# Ebean ManyToOne nullable join

Tags: java, sql, jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have two models :

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="table_entry")
public class TableEntry extends Model {

        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="clone_id", referencedColumnName="clone_id")
        public GeneData gene_data;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        public Long id;

        @Constraints.Required
        public String strain;
        public String clone_id;
        public String exp_type;
        ...
```

and

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="gene_data")
public class GeneData extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne 
    public List<TableEntry> entry;

    public String clone_id;
        public String gene_name;
        public String wb_id;
        ...
```

I would like to join `table_entry` on `clone_id`. However, not every row in `table_entry` has a row in `gene_data`. So I would want `gene_data` to be null when its not found during the join. Is this possible?

What am I doing wrong? I keep getting this error

```
We got the following error: 
Referential integrity constraint violation: 
"FK_TABLE_ENTRY_GENE_DATA_1: 
PUBLIC.TABLE_ENTRY FOREIGN KEY(CLONE_ID) REFERENCES 
PUBLIC.GENE_DATA(CLONE_ID) ('Y56A3A.19')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a row in table_entry with clone_id set to 'Y56A3A.19' but there isn't a row in gene_data with this value.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. My question is how do I make the join such that if a row doesn't exist in gene_data, null is just returned

Comment: I think is not possible to disable the integrity check..it's better if you correct the wrong rows